# SSIS: Join Headers and Records

Tags: ssis

I am trying to import xml files into SQL Server 2008R2 using SSIS. The structure of the files is frozen and is as goes (simplified):

```
<dailyReport>
  <header>
    <clientId>1234</clientId>
  </header>
  <dataRecord>
    <PosId>567</PosId>
    <recordValue>777</recordValue>
  </dataRecord>
  <dataRecord>
    <PosId>765</PosId>
    <recordValue>221</recordValue>
  </dataRecord>
</dailyReport>
```

The XML Source creates two outputs from this, one with a single record containing the header date and the other with the individual data points. I would like to join them so that I can export them into a single database table, containing clientId, PosId and recordValue columns. The problem is that Merge Join requires a common column on which to perform the join, which I don't have (and Merge and Union All both perform unions).

So how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try adding a derived column to each, always with the value 1.  Then you've got something to merge on.  Would that help your problem?

Comment: Yes! That solved it. I'm embarrassed that I asked such a trivial question, but I'm a complete newbie with SSIS and the Derived Column tool didn't catch my eye no matter how many times I went through the palette.

Sorry I don't have enough rep to upvote you yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

When I have to do this, I use a source connection and a destination connection (overwrite file  checked in connection) to pull the header and write it to a new file. 
Then I make another source and destination(**overwrite file unchecked in connection!**) and write to the same file.